# Can't translate my template (babel used)

Tags: babel, overleaf

I am working on a template in overleaf and there is used babel for translation so almost everything is in Spanish. I am trying to translate it in English.

I tried some modification but with no result.

I am sharing the project link with you: https://www.overleaf.com/1827398957whpbxycnbfpr

I need to translate MOSTLY the word Indice general. Just one example would be enough.

Thank you!

Comment: you should be able to make a small example by discarding everything not relevant to the question, to make an example showing the output from `\chapter` is not likely to be more than a few dozen lines, but if you really can not do that, a public link to overleaf is better than nothing

Comment: Have you tried to comment out or remove the line that looks like `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`?

Comment: Yes I tried. By posting the link I mean I will ommit everything from my project that is not related to this, but still te code is too long to post here.

Comment: So is there a ny solution?

Comment: You can edit it if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project uses `esi-tfm.cls`(source: https://bitbucket.org/arco_group/esi-tfg), which contains `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`.

To override this with English without modifying the `.cls`, add the following line *before* `\documentclass`:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{main=english}{babel}
```

Or if your intention *is* to modify the `.cls`, then you can simply comment out the `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` line.